# I've replaced almost all of my hardware and now I'm getting BSOD's. What's going on?

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I have an old desktop computer, and about a year or so ago I decided to start upgrading it.  I first replaced the power supply (the old one was clearly going bad) and I upgraded the graphics card to an AMD Radeon 7850.  The system worked fine like this for several months, but last January I decided I wanted a faster processor (AMD FX-8320).  This required upgrading my motherboard (ASRock 970 Pro3), and since my old ram was DDR2 I had to get new RAM as well.  Once I installed all this new hardware (I also finally upgraded from Windows XP to Windows 7), I started getting blue screens.  It wouldn't happen often or for any obvious reason; I would be performing some task (anything from checking my e-mail to installing software to playing a video game) and it would crash.

Upon doing several Google searches, I came up with a few ideas.  First, I tried replacing the RAM.  No luck - even when I tested one stick at a time.  Then I downloaded a utility which reports internal temperatures.  Nothing too scary - most of the system idled in the 30's and 40's and got up to the 50's and 60's under stress (the graphics card even got up to the 70's during intense gaming).  I'm still a little worried about temperatures simply because the CPU fan sounds like it's working hard even when the system is idle, but it does seem to be keeping the temperatures down.  So then I contacted tech support for my motherboard; they ultimately sent me a new one, I just installed it, and the BSOD's are happening again.

I should also mention that I have reinstalled windows almost half a dozen times during this process, wiping the hard drive clean each time.  After reinstalling, I only install fairly minimal software: ethernet driver, sound card driver, video card driver, Symantec antivirus, Firefox, Steam, a game or two, and eventually some diagnostic utilities.  All software installs have been fresh (though I install some of the drivers from the disk that shipped with the motherboard).

So just about the only piece of hardware that I haven't replaced is the hard drive (Hitachi HDP725050GLA360).  It is quite old, but I haven't noticed any other issues and there were no problems at all until I installed the new motherboard.  Could this be causing the problem?  Is there some way I can test it before I have to go out and buy a new one?  Any other ideas?  I really don't know what to do at this point...

---

UPDATE: I have dmp files from a couple of of crashes; is there any way to upload them here?  Most recently I got a PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA error if that helps.

Other than that, I downloaded the HDD Health program recommended below and it says that the hard drive health is at 100%.  Is there anything further I can do to diagnose the problem?

Comment: What are the error codes you get in the BSOD?

Comment: I've gotten various different ones, and for the last few crashes I haven't gotten any.  The only one I can remember for sure was IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL - that was before I got the replacement motherboard.

Comment: If you can analyze a crash dump when you have a IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL bugcheck you can find out which driver was causing it. Either it's a bug in the driver or (in your case probably) broken hardware.

Comment: Do you recommend a specific utility for analysing crash dumps?  And do you have any suspicions about which piece of hardware is faulty?

Comment: This video might help you to analyze a BSOD: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks

Comment: The tool might tell you which file caused the bsod. Look up the file in your system and find in the properties which company made it.

Comment: If the only thing you have not replaced is the hdd, and this happens on a clean installation of Windows across multiple reinstallations, you should replaced the hdd. Its one of the cheapest pieces of equipment to switch.  Purchase a cheap $59 hdd see if it helps things.  A bad hdd will cause bsod when trying to access systme files.

Comment: In _my_ experience those pesky IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL-BSODS are either RAM related (which you replaced) OR (and much more often): The power supply is bad. Even if yours is new, you are using it with a new Mainboard and CPU and it is totally possible that one of the now more or different burdened voltages are behaving funky, resulting in _all_ kinds of errors. 75% of all bad machines i had to fix since... ever, had bad power supplies. I now stick with brand names like enermax, be quiet! etc. Throw some money on the power supply, it will last longer than your current setup.

Comment: If you still want to check the HD, you might try HDD Heath. It's free and can be had at http://www.panterasoft.com

Comment: zip and upload the dmp files so that we can look at them with WinDbg

Answer (score 1):

IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL - can be caused by a number of things (RAM is include in this list)

PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA - is almost always bad, wrong model for your motherboard, and/or incorrectly installed RAM

First, double check that the ram you bought is compatible with your motherboard via the manufacturer's website(i.e. not all DDR3 RAM and DDR3 motherboards are compatible). If they indeed are compatible, then try re-seating your RAM sticks. If this doesn't work, try removing the sticks and using an air-duster on the sticks and the slots before re-installing. If again you continue getting BSODs then you'll have to try exchanging your RAM as you may have gotten faulty sticks from the retailer.

Only after all of this can you determine if the RAM is good or bad and this is all free unless you are outside of return policy or have to buy an air duster. If you do determine that the RAM is not bad then you can move to the HDD with the same process, but I would start with the RAM since it is the most likely culprit and that way buying another hard drive is the last resort.

Comment: I think I'll try buying new RAM and just return it if it doesn't help.  I've tried the RAM sticks in several configurations on two brand new copies of the same motherboard, but I just bought name-brand RAM (Corsair) without worrying about compatibility with the motherboard.  And I suppose the probability that I bought two sets of defective RAM in a row is nonzero.

Comment: @PaulSiegel Here's the [RAM compatibility list](http://www.asrock.com/mb/memory.asp?Model=970%20Pro3) for your motherboard. If your RAM sticks are on there then go buy a new hard drive. Just make sure it has a return policy because there's no guarantee that the HDD is bad, especially since it passed some hardware tests as you noted above.

Comment: All I remember for sure is that I have two Corsair 4GB sticks, and that doesn't appear anywhere on the list.  So maybe this is the problem!  I'll hit the computer store ASAP...

Comment: @PaulSiegel You'll have to look at the module # on the RAM sticks to compare them with that list. The number should look like a long serial number usually right in the middle of the Corsair sticker.